# Can't access UIView in external method

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm new to Objective-C, so the way I'm going about this might be ludicrous, but here goes:

I have a login form in my iPhone application. When the user has entered their credentials, they hit Done in the top right corner, which triggers an IBAction and a custom progress indicator pops up. I've created this indicator by using a class containing an instance method named **showProgressIndicator**. **showProgressIndicator** creates and returns a UIView, which I then add to my view like so:

```
ProgressIndicatorElement *ProgressIndicator = [[ProgressIndicatorElement alloc] init];
box = [ProgressIndicator showProgressIndicator];
[self.view addSubview:box];
```

I have of course declared box as a UIView in my header file. The progress indicator pops up beautifully and in the meantime I'm doing a behind-the-scenes URL request that, when finished, calls another method in my view controller named **receivedServerResponse**. Now, what I want to do is to remove the progress indicator, which is why I'm doing this:

```
- (void)receivedServerResponse {
    [box removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But nothing happens at all. I'm not getting any errors or warnings, and the code is being highlighted just as if everything was running smoothly. I've tried retaining the indicator in my IBAction, but that doesn't help either.

Hope you can help out!

**Updated:**

Here is the **showProgressIndicator** method:

```
- (UIView *)showProgressIndicator {
    box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 190, 210, 140)];
    box.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 / 255 green:0.0 / 255 blue:0.0 / 255 alpha:.6];
    box.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.layer.frame = CGRectMake((box.layer.bounds.size.width - spinner.layer.bounds.size.width)/2, 20, spinner.layer.bounds.size.width, spinner.layer.bounds.size.height);
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [box addSubview:spinner];

    UILabel *titleInBox = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 150, 20)];
    titleInBox.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    titleInBox.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleInBox.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    titleInBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleInBox.text = @"Authorizing...";
    [box addSubview:titleInBox];

    return box;
}
```

**Second update:**

@Deepak just pointed out in the comments that I might be running two different instances of my view controller, which actually seems to be the case. In the external class that handles the aforementioned URL request, I get back to the view controller's **receivedServerResponse** method by doing this:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    SignInViewController *viewController = [[SignInViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController receivedServerResponse];
}
```

Without spreading myself too thin (probably too late ;)), ASIHTTPRequest is set up so that if you call one method that performs an asynchronous URL request, a predefined method called **requestFinished** (above) is called, which is why I've had to call my view controller this way, because I can't access the returned value in an easier way (that I know of).

Comment: Is `ProgressIndicatorElement` a custom class? If so, the problem may lie there. This code looks fine.

Comment: @PengOne Yes, `ProgressIndicatorElement` is a custom class.

Comment: Can you add the code for `showProgressIndicator`?

Comment: By `nothing happens at all`, do you mean you aren't able to remove it or it doesn't even show up?

Comment: @Deepak It shows up just fine, but I'm not able to remove it, change its properties or access it in any way.

Comment: Have you verified that receivedServerResponse is actually being called? Put and NSLog in there and make sure that it is being called like you expect.

Comment: Are you calling `showProgressIndicator` more than once?

Comment: @Deepak Nope, just once.

Comment: And when you NSLog box in your receivedServerResponse does it come up with an object or with nil?

Comment: You should check whether the `box`s are different objects by logging them in both the methods you've shown. It doesn't make sense if they are. :)

Comment: When I use `NSLog(@"%@", box);` in the receivedServerResponse method, it says `(null)` in the console.

Comment: That's your problem. You are not holding a proper reference to box. You need to make box an ivar/property for your superview. Otherwise you cannot communicate with that object.

Comment: Can you enlighten me on how to do so? As I've said, I'm completely new to Objective-C.

Comment: Are there multiple instances of the same view controller? Because unless you are manually setting `box` to `nil` somewhere, it is impossible even if the object were deallocated for `box` to be nil. Try logging `self` in both methods to see if they are same object instances.

Comment: This is a great tutorial. Some of it will seem to basic for you but read through it and you should have a greater understanding of how to do what you want: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new instance of `SignInViewController` is not the correct way. It only seems correct to maintain a weak reference (`assign`ed property) of the `SignInViewController` object. Say your class is `RequestHandler`.

```
@interface RequestHandler: [..] {
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) SignInViewController * signInViewController;

@end

@implementation RequestHandler
@synthesize signInViewController;
[..]
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    [signInViewController receivedServerResponse];
}
@end
```

So when you're creating a `RequestHandler` object within the `SignInViewController` instance, you do,

```
RequestHandler * requestHandler = [[RequestHandler alloc] init];
requestHandler.signInViewController = self;
[..]
```

Note, you can also look at delegation and [`notifications`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043).

Comment: Boom. That was it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem may be with memory management. If `showProgressIndicator` does not return an autoreleased object, try releasing box after adding it as a subview, like so:

```
[self.view addSubview:box];
[box release];
```

`box` may not disappear if `box` is not deallocated when removed from the superview.

My other recommendation is that instead of doing it the way you are doing, creating a view, adding it, and then trying to removing it, you might want to try adding box as a subview when the login view is created and setting its `hidden` property to `YES` then unhiding it later when necessary.

**Based on your update:** You have some memory management issues in `showProgressIndicator`. Whenever you alloc an object, you should release it. In this case, release all of your variables after adding them as subviews as I mentioned above. box however should be returned as an autoreleased object since `showProgressIndicator` does not know when it will need to be released. For that you should replace `return box;` with `return [box autorelease];`

Comment: I have tried adding the indicator in the viewDidLoad method of my view controller, but that doesn't help (neither does your first suggestion).

Comment: Did you play around with the `hidden` property?

Comment: Yup, I did. It's funny, because I can edit and play with the progress indicator all I want in the IBAction method, but as soon as the editing takes place outside the IBAction, nothing happens.

Comment: +1 for `return [box autorelease]`, need to make sure that `removeFromSuperview` isn't tripping up on an over-retained object.

Comment: I've fixed the memory problems you pointed out and added `return [box autorelease];` to `showProgressIndicator`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the activity indicator a `stopAnimating` message when you want the animation to stop. There's no need to remove it from its superview; instead, simply make sure that its `hidesWhenStopped` property is set to `YES`.

Comment: He is adding a UIView not activity indicator. So stopping activity indicator will not work in this case.

Comment: The view instance contains an instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView` to which the `showProgressIndicator` method has sent a `startAnimating` message. To stop the animation, a `stopAnimating` he'll need to send a `stopAnimating` message to the `UIActivityIndicatorView` regardless of whether or not it's nested inside a subview.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the problem. Even if the activity indicator stops animating, the whole box view is still there.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding box view on window in appDelgate? Give a tag to your boxView and in the remove method get the boxView back by using tag. For example if you give tag 99

```
- (void)receivedServerResponse {
    UIView *box = [window viewWithTag:99];
    [box removeFromSuperview];
}
```

also you don't need to declare an instance variable in header file. and you can access progress indicator anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

> Without spreading myself too thin (probably too late ;)), ASIHTTPRequest is set up so that if you call one method that performs an asynchronous URL request, a predefined method called requestFinished (above) is called, which is why I've had to call my view controller this way, because I can't access the returned value in an easier way (that I know of).

ASIHTTPRequest calls -requestFinished: on the object you set as the request's delegate. You should design your classes such that this delegate object either has a reference to the view controller you want it to act on or has some means of notifying that view controller to take action.
The easiest solution might be to make the controller the request's delegate.

Comment: We're so close! Looks like there's only one hurdle left! To set the view controller as the delegate, I do this: `[request setDelegate:SignInViewController];` (which I have included in the top of the file), but I get the error: **expected expression before 'SignInViewController'**. What to do?

Comment: `setDelegate` expects a pointer to an instance of a class which conforms to the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate protocol, not the name of a class.